# What is the difference between Do and Do on error in Progress 4gl?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have observed that in both cases, statements under these two blocks will execute the same. I do not understand what the difference is. Please can you explain.

Comment: Can you show us some [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 4):

Not surprisingly `ON ERROR` has to do with error handling. You should read up on this in the online help/manual since there's lots of ways on what to do.

DO is basically just a block. Without anything else it really doesn't do a lot. Paired with statements like `TRANSACTION` or  `ON ERROR` it can greatly change how your program executes. You should check out the `NO-ERROR` statement as well. It also effects error handling.

In the below examples I force an error by trying to cast the string `HELLO` to an integer, this doesn't work of course.

> DO ON ERROR, RETRY

This will repeat the block if there's an error and setting `RETRY` to true. If you don't `LEAVE`  in the `RETRY`-block you will have a loop.

```
DO ON ERROR UNDO, RETRY:

    IF RETRY THEN DO:

        DISPLAY "RETRY".

        /* Do some cleanup or what else */
        LEAVE.
    END.

    i = INTEGER("HELLO").

END.
```

> DO ON ERROR, THROW

A perhaps more modern approach when `THROW` - `CATCH` is used. Note that this also supresses the error from appearing (a bit like `NO-ERROR`).

```
DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.

DO ON ERROR UNDO, THROW:

    i = INTEGER("HELLO").

END.

CATCH error AS Progress.Lang.Error :

    MESSAGE "We had an error".

END CATCH.
```

> DO:

The program will just halt on error

```
DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.

DO:

    i = INTEGER("HELLO").

END.
```

Answer (score 1):

The ON ERROR statement gives you control on what happens when the block fails. If you are using ROUTINE-LEVEL error handling for example, errors at the block level are not caught by default, so you can

```cs
DO ON ERROR UNDO,THROW:
END.
```

This will make sure the error is trapped. If you are using BLOCK-LEVEL error handling then this would be trapped by default.

This is just an example, and there are many things you can use ON ERROR for. Have a look at this documentation: https://help.consultingwerkcloud.com/openedge/117/rfi1424919692411.html